# How to edit doc from mail attachment in drive?

Tags: email, gmail, attachments

I have an email with a .doc or .xls attachment and I wanted to copy some text from it. JB 4.2 opens it by default with the "document viewer app", which doesn't allow copy/paste.

I tried downloading it, then sharing to Drive, but Drive doesn't show it as an editable document, and it still opens it with the "document viewer app", not with Drive editor.

Is there a way around this?